# How would you hyphenate a 4 word phrase?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, hyphenation

The context is "...how self-uncertainty affects attitudes toward non-group-identity-affiliated topics, such as..."
For some more context, "group identity" is a phrase in psychology. So my two thoughts are:
1) hyphens between every word
2) two hyphens: non-group identity-affiliated

Any thoughts?

edit: maybe I should just rephrase it to"...how self-uncertainty affects attitudes toward topics not affiliated with group identities, such as..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rephrase

> "*non-group-identity-affiliated-topics*"

as

> "***topics that are not affiliated with group identity***".