# Hyphenate 3/4 word compound adjective

Tags: hyphenation, writing, technical, compound-adjectives

The phrase I don't know how to hyphenate is

- asset type specific keywords and patterns

and the negated version

- non asset type specific keywords and patterns.

I looked around and found this Q&A [How would you hyphenate a 4 word phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204695/how-would-you-hyphenate-a-4-word-phrase), which more or less answers my question.
However, I'm using the phrases above as table headings in technical documentation, so I would prefer it to be more concise.

Comment: I'm inclined to say "asset-type specific keywords and patterns", where the compound adjective is just "asset-type". Would that fit the technical meaning?

Comment: The first 2 results from searching for the sequence ["**asset type specific**"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22asset+type+specific%22) in Google Books are #1 ("predicative" adjective, *after* the verb) *Objectives may in some cases be **asset type specific*** (no hyphen), and #2 ("standard" adjective before noun) *[Something applies to] each of the **asset-type-specific** loading methods*. In that second context, the "compound noun" being modified is "loading methods", and all elements in the "compound adjective" are connected by hyphens. That's the default orthography.

Comment: As BillJ implies, this is ambiguous. Can you put square brackets round closely-coherent words (eg [asset type] [specific] vs [asset type specific], please.

Comment: Don’t do it. Rewrite it in English.

Answer (score 1):

"Asset-type-specific keywords and patterns" - keywords and patterns that are of the type that are specific to assets.

"Non-asset-type-specific keywords and patterns" - keywords and patterns that are of the type that are  specific to non-assets.

Pub Med https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/97870/

> Type-specific and non-type-specific reactions of purified M protein preparations

Nature Neuroscience https://www.nature.com/articles/s41593-019-0479-z

> Cell-type-specific profiling of brain mitochondria reveals functional and molecular diversity.